# How to replace deleted vertices?

Tags: uv, vertices

New to Blender so sorry if this is a dumb question.  But it appears I forgot to turn off mirroring and accidentally deleted a vertex on the seam of my pants, leaving a hole in the texture.  How can I replace/recreate the deleted vertex?
[image: issue]

I have tried merging the vertices but it messes up vertices.  I know right clicking is supposed to create a new vertex but that doesn't do anything when i try it.  I'm using 2.79 on Mac.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm so close to finishing my first project but I'm stuck until i fix this issue.  Thanks[image]

Comment: The easiest Undo or go to File menu>Recovery>Auto Save, but I guess you tried it ... So select border, delete face and search for Grid Fill ... Or use a Knife tool, but all those reconstructions doesn't fix your UV map, you would have to unwrap again.

Comment: If you noticed it soon after your mistake you can either Edit:Undo (one or more times), or File:Recover. Either of these would require you to redo any other edits you made after your mistake that you wanted. There are also myFile.blend1, myFile.blend2 and myFile.blend3 in the same foldder that might help you recover (rename myFile.blend to myFile.blendPreDelete and then rename to remove the '1','2','3' so you can open these with blender.  Although my friends complain about my geeky motto: "when in doubt, reboot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem:

[image]

Select vertices 1 and 2. Press <kbd>J</kbd> to *join* them. This will create an edge, cutting through an existing face. Now you can right-click, *subdivide* and choose **3** as the number of new vertices (marked as 3, 4 and 5 above):

[image]

From here you could connect horizontal pairs 3 & 6, 4 & 7, 5 & 8, also by selecting a pair and pressing <kbd>J</kbd>. Then, finally, you can select vertices 9 & 10, press <kbd>J</kbd> to do a cut there as well to get quads. But then you need to press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for a *loop cut* to divide the quads above vertex 9 and below vertex 10. You would have to do the same right to 6 and 8.

Of course everything would be simpler if you just selected vertex 8, pressed <kbd>G</kbd> **twice** and moved it to the nearest vertex, similarly with vertices 6, 9 and 10, then if vertex auto-merging is disabled, you would press <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>B</kbd> to select all vertices and remove doubles, but I assumed those vertices are there for a reason.

Comment: I don't use a Mac and it's been a while since I used 2.79, so some shortcuts above might be incorrect (especially removing doubles).

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked perfectly